# "content-visibility: auto" hides an element in svg when scrolling in new chrome version (Version 121)

Tags: html, css, svg

After updating the chrome version (Version 121.0.6167.140), the property "content-visibility: auto" starts to hide the element even if it is displayed on the screen.

On this svg element on the right has a text block, but it is hidden.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="8747.5" height="142.5" viewBox="157.5 333.5 3499 57"><defs/><g><path d="M 162 334 L 318 334 C 320.21 334 322 335.79 322 338 L 322 386 C 322 388.21 320.21 390 318 390 L 162 390 C 159.79 390 158 388.21 158 386 L 158 338 C 158 335.79 159.79 334 162 334 Z" fill="#ecc283" stroke="none" pointer-events="none"/><image x="163" y="347" width="30" height="30" pointer-events="none"/><foreignObject x="201" y="341" width="114" height="42" transform="" style="content-visibility:auto;pointer-events:none;overflow:unset;">
                <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex;             overflow: hidden;             text-align: center;             height: 100%;             align-items: center;             justify-content: center; ">
                    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="-webkit-line-clamp:3;             display: -webkit-box;             -webkit-box-orient: vertical;             word-break: break-word;             overflow: hidden;             font-size: 11px;             font-family: Arial;             color: #000000;             line-height: 1.2;             pointer-events: none;" class="cont">
                        Исполнитель
                    </div>
                </div>
            </foreignObject><path d="M 3496 334 L 3652 334 C 3654.21 334 3656 335.79 3656 338 L 3656 386 C 3656 388.21 3654.21 390 3652 390 L 3496 390 C 3493.79 390 3492 388.21 3492 386 L 3492 338 C 3492 335.79 3493.79 334 3496 334 Z" fill="#c9f0eb" stroke="none" pointer-events="none"/><image x="3497" y="347" width="30" height="30" pointer-events="none"/><foreignObject x="3535" y="341" width="114" height="42" transform="" style="content-visibility:auto;pointer-events:none;overflow:unset;">
                <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex;             overflow: hidden;             text-align: center;             height: 100%;             align-items: center;             justify-content: center; ">
                    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="-webkit-line-clamp:3;             display: -webkit-box;             -webkit-box-orient: vertical;             word-break: break-word;             overflow: hidden;             font-size: 11px;             font-family: Arial;             color: #000000;             line-height: 1.2;             pointer-events: none;" class="cont">
                        Задача (повторяющаяся)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </foreignObject><path d="M 322 362 L 3492 362" fill="none" stroke="#6482b9" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/></g></svg>
```

If you remove the property "content-visibility: auto", the text block is displayed normally. But I would like to leave this property for optimization.

Comment: If you've found a Chrome bug, report it to [Chrome's bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/)